# How do I change the "open terminal" hotkeys to others in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: command-line, 20.04

By default, the terminal is opened with `CTRL + ALT + T`. I want the terminal to open for me, for example, with the right `Shift` key, or for example with the right `Ctrl`.

For some reason, in Settings -> Keyboard Shourcuts, I can not select either the right Shift or the right Ctrl. Although other keys can be selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to settings,then click on keyboard shortcuts,then with the search bar at the top ,search 'terminal',then you will see the 'launch terminal' hotkey,just click on it,enter the hotkey you want and click 'set'.

Comment: For some reason, in Settings -> Keyboard Shourcuts, I can not select either the right Shift or the right Ctrl. Although other keys can be selected.

Comment: @antongordon25 yeah unfortunately that is a limitation of ubuntu.