# Opening the terminal on the computer

Tags: bash

I tried to initialize the key combination:
t + ctrl + alt and the terminal did not open for me

Anyone know exactly where to write this?

Comment: it is CTRL + ALT + t and you can do it from anywhere

Comment: What kind of OS the computer is running?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the "open terminal" hotkeys to others in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375468/how-do-i-change-the-open-terminal-hotkeys-to-others-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 2):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>to open Terminal.

or

2. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> key (Windows logo key) and type Terminal

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then press and release <kbd>t</kbd>. That should launch the terminal. You now can also release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>.